# This is one thing I do not understand in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, closures, completionhandler

Consider these lines:

I create a `NSButton` based class with this:

```
typealias onClickHandler = (NSTextfieldSuper)->Void
var onClick: onClickHandler?
```

When the user clicks on an instance of that button, I do this:

```
if (self.onClick != nil) {
   onClick?(self)
}
```

I use that button later, from another class, with this:

```
let button = SuperButton()
button.onClick = { (textField: NSTextfieldSuper)->Void in 
}
```

I am not sure if this is the correct syntax. I would like to process the button sent from the first closure on the parent class, where the button is created.

This was the only form I was able to type this without Xcode complaining. If this is correct, what is the purpose of this `->Void` there? What could this possibly returning?

I just want to process that button sent.

By the way, as a bonus, I have to initialize several buttons with this, all running the same function. It would be nice to do something like

```
func doSomething () {
}
```

and then

```
let button = SuperButton()
button.onClick = doSomething
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This was the only form I was able to type this without Xcode complaining. If this is correct, what is the purpose of this `->Void` there? What could this possibly returning?

It is the same as in your `typealias`, in Swift a function type has the form:

> (*parameter definitions*) -> *return type*

and functions which return nothing have a return type of `Void` (similar to C). The *full* form off a closure expression is:

> `{ (`*parameter definitions*`) ->`*return type*`in`*body*`}`

Without any inference this expression provides the full type of the closure, and the `-> Void` Return type in your example specifies that your closure returns nothing. In your assignment this full type will be checked at compile time to conform to the type of `onClick`.

Now Swift will infer lots of stuff and there are various shorthands available for closure expressions, you will find that Swift accepts:

```
button.onClick = { textField in }
```

as well here with both the argument and return types of the closure being inferred.

> By the way, as a bonus, [...] any ideas?

Just make the types match:

```
func doSomething(textField : NSTextfieldSuper) { }
button.onClick = doSomething
```

Unlike in (Objective-)C functions and closures (blocks in C) are interchangeable (as they are in plenty of other languages, C is the oddfellow here)

HTH

Comment: I see thanks but regarding the first part of my question I think I was unable to express myself. What I mean is this: the part `(textField: NSTextfieldSuper)->Void` inside that closure is already passing the variable `textField` to inside the closure. What is the point of the `->Void` part? It makes no sense?

Comment: It is like saying: take this thing that returns void but returns textField...(?) Imagine this was not void, but Bool or something.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you but I've added a bit to the answer, does that answer your concern over the purpose of the `-> Void`?

Comment: sorry but I do not understand the void part but anyway I will not bother you more about this.

Comment: @SpaceDog - One last try: Compilers in general need to know what a function/closure returns so the correct code can be produced for the call etc. e.g. return values have to go somewhere - a machine register, on the stack, into pre-allocated storage - and this depends on the return type and impacts the pre- and post-call code the compiler must generate. The `Void` return type (written or inferred) in Swift tells the compiler that nothing will be returned from a call, so correct call site code is produced, and that there should be no `return` in the function/closure body. HTH, O-O on this one.

Comment: ok, I see that, but could a function like that return something in the way we are using it there. Would this be possible? `button.onClick = { (textField: NSTextfieldSuper)->Bool in  }` be possible?

Comment: @SpaceDog - the closure is not valid as its (missing) body doesn't evaluate to a `Bool`, but if that was fixed the closure itself would be valid. However the assignment would be invalid as the LHS & RHS types don't match. If you are asking whether a button handler can return a value the answer is no - simply because the software architecture of buttons specifies a handler that returns nothing and not because of any restriction in Swift. This is the same handler architecture that you know from Obj-C (and in Obj-C you provide handlers which in Obj-C-ese return nothing).

Comment: AHHH, That was the thing I was not understanding. It was not making sense to declared a void there because it would make no sense anything other than a void, or in other words, why to declare void if void is the only allowed thing to go there? Now I see thanks!!!!